# Is it possible to access a table Variable declared in one SP to Another SP?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, temp-tables

I had a situation where I needed to remove this TEMPORARY TABLE and need to substitute a TABLE VARIABLE or any other methods.

Is it possible to get the scope of the table variable created in SP_1 in SP_2?

Or is there any other method by which I can Substitute this TEMPORARY TABLE.Global Temporary tables are also not allowed.Please let me know

The Sample of the SP is as given (Objective is that I need to substitute this TEMPORARY TABLE):

```
Create Procedure SP_1     
(     
CREATE TABLE #T(ID INT NOT NULL)     
INSERT INTO #T     
VALUES(1),(2)     
)

Create Procedure SP_2     
(     
 Select * from #T     
INSERT INTO #T     
VALUES(3),(5)     
SELECT * FROM #T     
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Temporary tables only last for the duration of the scope in which they're declared. I.e. when you exit SP1, the temp table will no longer be available for use.

Is there any reason why you need this specific functionality? Can't you combine the SPs into a single one?